# Typescript and webstorm, missing --module flag

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

Editing a typescript project, that was created on VisualStudio, in WebStorm is replying this error:

> Error:(1, 1) TS1148: Cannot compile external modules unless the
>   '--module' flag is provided.

the code is simple like this:

*in file Test.ts*

```
class helloWorld{

}

export = helloWorld;
```

Thanks in advance for your help

**EDITED**

I forgot to mention that I was using a MAC.

Also after enter the post, on my quest to find the solution, I try to compile the web in VisualStudio Code for Mac, and I have the same problem there, that, make realize that the problem was not the IDE but something in common, that I didn't figure it out.

On fedemp answer this sentence trigger someting:

> One is using the flag at compilation: tsc --module commonjs or --module amd.

So I go to Webstorm's Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript and on the option *"Command line options:"* I added *--module amd* and done!

Comment: I had the exact same error but in IntelliJ on PC (virtually same as webstorm I think) 14.1.3 after importing a TS project that was working fine outside of IntelliJ.
Solved by File->Settings->Languages & Frameworks-> Typescript and adding --module commonjs to the 'command line options:'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-export- It's the official documentation for Typescript, the section about `export =`.

When you use `export =`, you are creating an external module to be consumed using AMD or CommonJS. That's why the compiler complains.

You have to two options depending on your needs. One is using the flag at compilation: `tsc --module commonjs` or `--module amd`. Use this if you want to use NodeJS or require.js.

The other is `export class HelloWorld {...` if you want to use your class in another typescript file.

Comment: thanks fedemp, you answer make find the solution... lets say you was 50% right :P
I just edit the question to add more relevant information in order to help others in future.

Answer (score 8):

For those of you that are using VisualStudio, I did the following on VS2015 and the error went away.

Right click on the project in Solution Explorer --> Properties-->TypeScript Build (last tab on the left--below Code Analysis) in the Module System section change None to AMD.

Comment: This got me to resolve the issue but for future visitors choosing 'AMD' may not be correct option for you as it was 'System' I had to change it to as correct option depends on system you use for your modules.  I also had to change 'JSX compilation' to remove all my errors